# jQuery validation before sending ajax request

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that lets the user edit SMTP information. All required fields have class="required". The form has two buttons.

1. Save
2. Test

**1) Save**

When a user clicks the save button, the jQuery validator checks if all required fields have some content (class="required"), then submits the form in a normal manner. This works as expected.

**2) Test**

When a user clicks the test button, I use $.getJSON to find out whether the entered information works. However, there is no validation going on before the ajax request is sent. I want the same fields to be required for this button.

**How can I accomplish this?**

The problem seems to be that the way I have set it up, there's never a submit action that triggers the validation. Is the solution to use the jQuery validator submitHandler option? If so, how do I determine which button was clicked?

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#testEmailProfile').click(function() {
        var map = { 
            m: 'testEmailProfile', 
            smtpHostname: $('#smtpHostname').val(),
            smtpPort: $('#smtpPort').val(),
            smtpUsername: $('#smtpUsername').val(),
            smtpPassword: $('#smtpPassword').val(),
        }
        $.getJSON('ajax.php', map, function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                //Works
            } else {
                //Doesn't work
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#emailProfileForm").validate();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The placement of $("#emailProfileForm").validate(); is wrong here. Validation functions should be called before sending ajax request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#testEmailProfile').click(function() {
        if($("#emailProfileForm").validate()) {
            var map = { 
                m: 'testEmailProfile', 
                smtpHostname: $('#smtpHostname').val(),
                smtpPort: $('#smtpPort').val(),
                smtpUsername: $('#smtpUsername').val(),
                smtpPassword: $('#smtpPassword').val(),
            }
            $.getJSON('ajax.php', map, function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    //Works
                } else {
                    //Doesn't work
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

If you are using jquery form validator pludgin, please read more from [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

Answer (score 0):

I split the form into two separate forms, then did this:

```
$("#emailProfileForm").validate();

$("#testEmailProfileForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function() {
        var map = { 
            m: 'testEmailProfile', 
            smtpHostname: $('#smtpHostname').val(),
            smtpPort: $('#smtpPort').val(),
            smtpUsername: $('#smtpUsername').val(),
            smtpPassword: $('#smtpPassword').val(),
        }
        $.getJSON('ajax.php', map, function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                //Success
            } else {
                //Not success
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Probably not the optimal solution...

Answer (score 0):

Jquery validator provides submit handler for this

```
$(".selector").validate({

   submitHandler: function(form) {

      $(form).ajaxSubmit();
   }
 });
```

So you can include all your codes inside submitHandler function. That will get executed after validation results success.